# Getting bit sequence from a trie for huffman coding

Tags: c, trie, huffman-code

i currently have a trie built from the frequence of how many times a char appears in a in File. Now im trying to go from the root to each child and build a bit sequence for every letter (each leaf is a letter). Im using a preorder whilest doing this and everytime it goes to the left child of a node it´s suppose to add a "1" to the bit sequence and right a "0". However i cant find a good way to do this, i have tried using strings with strncat() and then when i found a leaf i have trouble removing the last char from the string so i have used strncpy(thestring, thestring, strlen(thestring) - 1) etc etc. Is there any way to walk trough the whole tree and add the bit?

```
Table *fill_table(node *root, Table *hufftable, bit_buffer *b)
{
if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
    hufftable[(int)root->data].bseqe = bit_buffer_to_string(b);
    bit_buffer_remove_bit(b);
    return hufftable;
}
else{
    bit_buffer_insert_bit(b, 1);
    fill_table(root->left, hufftable, b);
    bit_buffer_insert_bit(b, 0);
    fill_table(root->right, hufftable, b);
}

return hufftable;
```

}

This is an example of what i have trie, the issue with this is that 1. it gets seg fault and 2. the bitbuffer is given to us(this is a school assignment) and we are not allowed to change it. the bit_buffer_remove_bit takes away the first bit in the sequence not the last

Comment: should really show a [mcve].

Comment: If you've been given a list of functions that you're required to use, then you need to post the full list, along with the documentation for each function.

Comment: Instead of appending to the bit buffer passed in, perhaps you can make a local copy and append to that for the recursive call. That way there's no need for removal.